# iPhone - UITableView : change default Edit button name

Tags: iphone, uitableview, label, edit

I have a usual editButtonItem in my navigationBar (created by the system), and I'd like to change its name. Si I wrote this lines in my TableViewController :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [Some code...]

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"New name";
}
```

That works, but when entering and exiting the Edit Mode, its system name is restored.
I tried to force it again in `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` for example, but with no success...

What should I do to fix this custom name **without having to build the button from start by myself in the code** ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@Bojan's method is close but very inefficient, since it gets called for every single row. Just change the title at the beginning on `viewDidLoad` and in addition do this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Make sure you call super first
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing)
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Addition: on `viewDidLoad` call self.editing = NO!

Answer (score 5):

Create your own edit button item if you don't like the name of the existing one.

Declare an ivar editItem in your header then create the item like so:

```
    editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Name" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)]
```

in -toggleEditing, call

```
[self setEditing:!self.editing animated:YES]
```

and also update the title of the button (and optionally the appearance) to reflect the editing state.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   if (self.tableView.editing) {
     self.editButtonItem.title =  @"CustomDoneName";
   }
   else
     self.editButtonItem.title = @"CustomEditName";
   return YES;
}
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement these answers. Custom is the way to go **BUT** keep in mind:

If you do create your own button, which will change title, make sure you set it's **possibleTitles** property.

```
self.myEditButton.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Edit Seats", @"Done", nil];
```

Otherwise, the transition animation on your button may get weird, especially if the titles differ in length significantly. The reason for this is, we change the button's title as it's animating being tapped on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way I found out to fix the temporary shrunk dirty transition state of the editButtonItem when toggling the button with custom titles.

Even setting possibleTitles does not provide a perfect result.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{    
    NSString *editButtonTitleBefore = self.editButtonItem.title;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self setToolbarLayout];

    if (editing && ![self.editButtonItem.title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel")])
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel");
    }
    else if (!editing && ![editButtonTitleBefore isEqualToString:@"Edit"])
    {
        // Dirty hax to avoid the editButton system title label shrink bug
        self.editButtonItem.title = @"";
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 you should override the setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) UIViewController's method as bellow:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if self.isEditing {
        self.editButtonItem.title = "[New editing title]"
    }
    else {
        self.editButtonItem.title = "[New to edit title]"
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you should call this method on viewDidLoad to the editButtonItem starts on the view with the correct title, as bellow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}
```